# Jenkins: Single job with multiple subversion modules

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, jenkins

I am using Jenkins for a project and would like to know if the following is possible. I have four separate SVN modules which are checked out as part of the job. Each SVN module is added to a separate directory. Depending on which module is updated during the SCM polling, I would like to only build certain directories.

With Cruise Control, I was able to set a variable for each module that was updated and passed those variables to the ant build script to control the build.

Has anyone done anything similar or have any ideas?

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: I would have four different build configuration for every module. 
Every configuration will have VCS changes build trigger.
If there are dependencies in modules than modules will be build in order.

Comment: Thanks, Eugen. We ended up going with this approach since each module is fairly independent.

Comment: Sean, different build configurations are not that good solution. Please look through this plugin description https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Workflows+Plugin or this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14246670/1435741

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Question is pretty complex. You are touching too much different parts of CI builserver and some tasks out of it.

Basically ... providing job / project in Jenkins with information that controls behavior of build itself is not best way, but if you have no other option, well, then you have no other option.

Build itself should be enough agnostic and it should contain all the parameters enabling build to be successful both in CI, and in Workstation ( from cmd.exe, for example ).

> Depending on which module is updated during the SCM polling, I would
>   like to only build certain directories.

So basically you want Maven build system, which provides model/module based conditional build, not building one single Project, like Ant does.

> With Cruise Control, I was able to set a variable for each module that
>   was updated and passed those variables to the ant build script to
>   control the build.

Here you want to have some kind of similar Build Triggering capability. Here comes place where without more detailed explanation of requirements only thing I can suggest is to check out Pramatreized Build Trigger plugin, which would allow to trigger build by parameters you set.

> Has anyone done anything similar or have any ideas?

Finally, here you can also check out this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin

In the conclusion, some features are provided by Jenkins out-of-the-box, so if you use Ant, you can easily use Environment variables and start building your needed behavior. Usually after investing some time by thinking how to do something without help from tons of Jenkins plugins it somehow makes you really understand, what is the key of thing you want to achieve.

Hope I helped somewhat. Cheers, mate.